# ZMQ_CONFLATE does not work for ZMQ_SUB (no filters)

Tags: c++, zeromq, ethernet, tcp

I have zeromq-4.1.4 library and cppzmq installed on a real-time fast server and a slow client.

Both client and server have 2 ports for publishing and subscribing, communicating over TCP-IP.

The server sends messages at it's own fast rate. Client receives the latest message, does some slow computation and send the message back to server. Server reads the message if there is an incoming and processes it.

Problem is that old messages are not overwritten with new. Client always prints out older messages, and even if I switch off the server, messages continue to be queued from a receive buffer of the client.

Why does it happen? ZMQ_CONFLATE is set. Should not it just work?

As a workaround I though to put a client in a worker thread to work on a maximum rate and then keep the last message manually. But this is an overhead, as this is exactly what zeromq does when it send or receives messages as far as I understand.

Client/server code is same:

```
void ZeromqMessenger::init(const char* pubAddress, const char* subAddress, const char* syncAddress, int flags)
{
  flags_ = flags;
  int confl = 1;

  // Prepare our context
  context_ = new zmq::context_t(1);

  // Prepare ZMQ publisher
  publisher_ = new zmq::socket_t(*context_, ZMQ_PUB);
  publisher_->bind(pubAddress);
  publisher_->setsockopt(ZMQ_CONFLATE, &confl, sizeof(confl)); // Keep only last message

  // Prepare ZMQ subscriber
  subscriber_ = new zmq::socket_t(*this->context_, ZMQ_SUB);
  subscriber_->connect(subAddress);
  subscriber_->setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);
  subscriber_->setsockopt(ZMQ_CONFLATE, &confl, sizeof(confl)); // Keep only last message

  if (flags_ & ZMQ_SYNC_PUB)
  {
    syncService_ = new zmq::socket_t(*context_, ZMQ_REP);
    syncService_->bind(syncAddress);
  }

  if (flags_ & ZMQ_SYNC_SUB)
  {
    // synchronize with publisher
    syncService_ = new zmq::socket_t(*context_, ZMQ_REQ);
    syncService_->connect(syncAddress);

    // - send a synchronization request
    zmq::message_t message(0);
    syncService_->send(message);

    // - wait for synchronization reply
    zmq::message_t update;
    syncService_->recv(&update);
  }
}

void ZeromqMessenger::sync()
{
  if (connected_)
    return;

  if (flags_ & ZMQ_SYNC_PUB)
  {
    //std::cout << "Waiting for subscribers" << std::endl;
    if (subscribers_ < subscribers_expected_)
    {
      // - wait for synchronization request
      zmq::message_t update;
      if (syncService_->recv(&update, ZMQ_DONTWAIT))
      {
        // - send synchronization reply
        zmq::message_t message(0);
        syncService_->send(message);

        subscribers_++;
      }
    }

    if (subscribers_ == subscribers_expected_)
      connected_ = true;
  }
}

void ZeromqMessenger::send(const void* data, int size) const
{
  zmq::message_t message(size);
  memcpy(message.data(), data, size);
  publisher_->send(message);
}

bool ZeromqMessenger::recv(void *data, int size, int flags) const
{
  zmq::message_t update;
  bool received = subscriber_->recv(&update, flags);
  if(received)
    memcpy(data, update.data(), size);
  return received;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the threaded version and it works just fine. This is a very crude implementation with global variables, which shall be refined, but at least it works.

```
#include <zmq_messenger.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::string gSubAddress;
std::mutex gMtx;
const int gSize = 20*sizeof(double);
char gData[gSize];

void *worker_routine (void *context)
{
  // Prepare ZMQ subscriber
  int confl = 1;
  zmq::socket_t* subscriber = new zmq::socket_t(*(zmq::context_t*)context, ZMQ_SUB);
  subscriber->connect(gSubAddress.c_str());
  subscriber->setsockopt(ZMQ_CONFLATE, &confl, sizeof(confl)); // Keep only last message
  subscriber->setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);

  while (1)
  {
    zmq::message_t update;
    bool received = subscriber->recv(&update, ZMQ_DONTWAIT);
    if(received)
    {
      gMtx.lock();
      memcpy(gData, update.data(), gSize);
      gMtx.unlock();
    }
  }
  zmq_close(subscriber);
  return NULL;
}

void ZeromqMessenger::init(const char* pubAddress, const char* subAddress, const char* syncAddress, int flags)
{
  flags_ = flags;
  int confl = 1;

  // Prepare our context
  context_ = new zmq::context_t(1);

  // Prepare ZMQ publisher
  publisher_ = new zmq::socket_t(*context_, ZMQ_PUB);
  publisher_->bind(pubAddress);
  publisher_->setsockopt(ZMQ_CONFLATE, &confl, sizeof(confl)); // Keep only last message

  gSubAddress = std::string(subAddress);
  pthread_create (&subscriber_worker_, NULL, worker_routine, context_);

  if (flags_ & ZMQ_SYNC_PUB)
  {
    syncService_ = new zmq::socket_t(*context_, ZMQ_REP);
    syncService_->bind(syncAddress);
  }

  if (flags_ & ZMQ_SYNC_SUB)
  {
    //std::cout << "Trying to connect" << std::endl;

    // synchronize with publisher
    syncService_ = new zmq::socket_t(*context_, ZMQ_REQ);
    syncService_->connect(syncAddress);

    // - send a synchronization request
    zmq::message_t message(0);
    syncService_->send(message);

    // - wait for synchronization reply
    zmq::message_t update;
    syncService_->recv(&update);

    // Third, get our updates and report how many we got
    //std::cout << "Ready to receive" << std::endl;
  }
}

void ZeromqMessenger::sync()
{
  //std::cout << "sync" << std::endl;
  if (connected_)
    return;

  if (flags_ & ZMQ_SYNC_PUB)
  {
    //std::cout << "Waiting for subscribers" << std::endl;
    if (subscribers_ < subscribers_expected_)
    {
      // - wait for synchronization request
      zmq::message_t update;
      if (syncService_->recv(&update, ZMQ_DONTWAIT))
      {
        // - send synchronization reply
        zmq::message_t message(0);
        syncService_->send(message);

        subscribers_++;
      }
    }

    if (subscribers_ == subscribers_expected_)
      connected_ = true;

    //std::cout << subscribers_ << " subscriber(s) connected" << std::endl;
  }
}

void ZeromqMessenger::send(const void* data, int size) const
{
  zmq::message_t message(size);
  memcpy(message.data(), data, size);
  publisher_->send(message);
}

bool ZeromqMessenger::recv(void *data, int size, int flags) const
{
  assert(gSize == size);
  gMtx.lock();
  memcpy(data, gData, size);
  gMtx.unlock();
  return true;
}
```